# Django: List of users in a model's field

Tags: django

I have a User model and PromoCode model. In the latter, I want to list users that have inputed and matched with one of the promocodes i put in the admin view.

What field type should I use in the PromoCode model to create a list of users, to which I can add more users over time in my views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `ManyToManyField`.

In the model:

```
class PromoCode(models.Model):
    # Assuming you have other fields here, followed by:
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="promocodes")
```

Then in the views you can do things like:

```
if promocode:
    pc = PromoCode.objects.get(code=promocode) # Get the PromoCode object
    pc.users.add(user) # Add the M2M relationship
```

...or (because you used `related_name`) you could do it the other way around:

```
if promocode:
    pc = PromoCode.objects.get(code=promocode) # Get the PromoCode object
    user.promocodes.add(pc) # Add the M2M relationship
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You have many `PromoCode`s that can have many `User`s, so you want a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: That seems to include all users though. I would want to only have those that have inputed that promo code and matched with it.

Comment: I would suggest this answer as a good one, all your logic @ThomasMartres must be done before adding the instance to ManytoManyField

Comment: I realized I was confused about the admin view widget that showed all users and I didn't understand that the highlighted ones were those that were added.